# Unpermitted parameters in Carrierwave file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have Rails 4 + CarrierWave + Nested form for `Ad` model which as many `Image` (mount `PictureUploader` as `picture`)

When I try to add or edit `Ad`, I have unpermitted parameters `picture`

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"ad"=>{
   "title"=>"plot", 
   "images_attributes"=>
      { "0" => 
         { 
            "picture"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fbea1ddedb8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/t8/fm77jh7j6232v5km2llkgq1r0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140921-33609-54hs6k>, @original_filename="New-york-rental-apartment-1-.gif", @content_type="image/gif", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ad[images_attributes][0][picture][]\"; filename=\"New-york-rental-apartment-1-.gif\"\r\nContent-Type: image/gif\r\n">],
            "_destroy"=>"false"
         }
      }
   }
}

Unpermitted parameters: parent_id
Unpermitted parameters: parent_id
Unpermitted parameters: picture
```

I permitted the param with following. (according to [this Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#more-examples), my code should be working)

```
params.require(:ad).permit(:picture, :title, :images_attributes => [:picture, :id, :_destroy])
```

I only get fallback picture from carrierwave and now I'm clueless.

EDIT 1:

Found [this issue](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/786) on github discussing about Carrierwave not working with nested forms.

Also found [A complete sample of how to perform nested polymorphic uploads in rails using carrierwave](https://gist.github.com/978371). It is in Rails 3 and I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following tutorials after tutorials and messed up my code. [A complete sample of how to perform nested polymorphic uploads in rails using carrierwave](https://gist.github.com/978371) works.

I was using `nested_form` and configure `file` to accept multiple files. I changed my each file input to accept only one and it is now working.